# React - useEffect even when there is no change

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to save an object to the DB.

The flow goes like this:

1. Fetch the updated data from DB (use API for that) and present it to the user and keep it in a `useState` var.
2. The user changes the data and presses "Save".
3. Fetching again the updated data from the DB in case another user made changes.
4. Updating the last fetched data with the new changes and send for update (using API).

currently, I'm stuck from 2 reasons:

1. The data is fetched into a state so I need to "wait" until the new data will be asynchrony set into the state.
   I read that the only option is to use `useEffect` although it's not the cleanest solution.
   (so the `useEffect` will contain all the update logic which is dangerous in case the data changes without save. I can use save flag but still not the best approach.)

this is the what I thought could be the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isSave) {
    save()
    setSave(false)
  }
}, [dataFetched])
```

2. Even if I'll use the `useEffect`, in case the "old" data will be the same as the new data, the `useEffect` won't be fired, and the data won't be saved.

What can I do?

Comment: How do you fetch data? Various approaches have very different solutions for this (_plain_ redux, redux with middleware where you can `await dispatch(...)`, `fetch()` API, `useSWR()`, etc). However...I personally would NOT do this client side. No matters what you try there could always be a conflict, this scenario should be handled server side when attempting to update data and the client should _only_ handle the 409 response (which you should anyway because server will always need to do it)

Comment: You can set an initial value for your save `let [save, setSave] = React.useState(initialValue)`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti 1. I'm using API. updated the question.  2. Our server gets the entire object and saves it as is (after validation). How can he determine if the diffs are from the user or conflict?

Comment: @bubulledu93 how does it help me? I'm afraid that useEffect will be triggered without pressing save somehow. it's not something I can control because it depends on something that related to a state.

Comment: 1. Yes, you're using an API but how you call it (and how you get back its result) is what makes the difference here. 2. server MUST perform this validation, it's not something you can leave to the client (which could be bypassed/tampered). Imagine if I can override your airplane reservation with my own data after you successfully booked a seat (because the server doesn't check and it trusts the clients). In practice: do this server side and the web client _just_ needs to properly handle the 409 HTTP status code (inform the user? try to perform _reconciliation_?)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti 1. result = await axios.post(server + url, body, reqOpts); 2. I understand what you're saying, but first, the system is internal. second, this is the backend. except for validations related to the data itself it doesn't make any conflict validations. Takes the data as is and save it. Not our code but another team's, and currently it's not an option to change it.....

Comment: If you're already `await` the result then you shouldn't need to check `dataFetched`, just `await`, compare and save within the same function (provide relevant code for a more targeted answer)